# Move Queues between instances with Force.com Migration Tool (Ant)?

Tags: migration-tool

I know I can move Queues from instance to instance using Change Sets, but is there any way to do it with the Force.com Migration Tool (Ant)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you can. It's called a Queue object.

Example is from the manual:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Queue xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<doesSendEmailToMembers>true</doesSendEmailToMembers>
<email>member@company.com</email>
<fullName>Your Name</fullName>
<name>memberQueue</name>
<queueSobject>
<sobjectType>Case</sobjectType>
</queueSobject>
<queueSobject>
<sobjectType>Lead</sobjectType>
</queueSobject>
<queueSobject>
<sobjectType>ObjA_c</sobjectType>
</queueSobject>
</Queue>
```

Take a look at the [Metadata API documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/api_meta.pdf). You can retrieve all of them through the package.xml wildcard (*).